# What is the most efficient way to join multiple tables with the same index/col?

Tags: python, bash, awk, sed, pandas

I have multiple tables like this saved in CSVs.

```
Table 1: Columns A,B
Table 2: Columns A,C
Table 3: Columns A,D
Table 4: Columns A,E
Table 5: Columns A,F
Table 6: Columns A,G
```

All values are floating point, except for Column A. Column A is not set as an index, though using pandas I have that option. All entries for Column A are the same throughout all the tables.

I want to create a table with columns A,B,C,D,E,F,G for the purpose of computing a weighted sum of columns B-G.  I have two general things I'm thinking:

1. What is the best way to create a pandas dataframe with these columns? By 'best', I mean keep the ram low, and hopefully utilize some kind of parallel computing.
2. I want to persist this dataframe on disk, so I am thinking maybe there is a better way using command line tools like sed/awk/cut to get a csv going which I can then just load.  Any tips there?

Answer (score 1):

I would just read in the data from the CSVs, join, dump to a master CSV.

Something like:

```
data = None
filelist = ['CSV1.csv', 'otherfile.csv', ..., 'Lastfile.csv']
for f in filelist:
    if data is None:
        data = pandas.read_csv(f, index_col='A')
    else:
        data = data.join(pandas.read_csv(f, index_col='A'))

data.to_csv('Big.csv')
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say without you posting some concrete input and expected output but it sounds like the UNIX utility `join` is what you're looking for.

Comment: I was 50/50 on that but it seems like comments are best for asking for more information about or suggesting ways to improve a question or answer. I'm doing neither here, I'm suggesting the answer is `join`.

Comment: I think suggestions are valid comments,especially on open ended questions like this. To be fair the answer is probably join though!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to persist large amounts of data on disk, csv is the wrong way to go, there is no standard, and the only datatype is characters. The use-case for csv is when you have a small amount of data that you'd like to eyeball, and you're the only one who needs to access the data so lack of a standard isn't a big problem. But even if it's just for you, if you come back to your data later, will you remember all of the specifications you used and conditions under which you encode the data? For rather small datasets, it's less of a problem, because you can visually inspect the entire thing. For larger datasets, you should use sqlite or a heftier relational database to persist data.

> Q. **"What is the most efficient way to join multiple tables with the same index/col?"**

I think `pd.merge` may be the best approach. Here's some sample data:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> t1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3,4], 'b': [5,5,5,5]})
>>> t2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3,4], 'c': [6,6,6,6]})
>>> t3 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3,4], 'd': [7,7,7,7]})
```

Unfortunately merge only takes two tables at a time, so you'd need to nest them or use reduce. Here's a merge that uses the index:

```
>>> pd.merge(pd.merge(t1, t2), t3)
   a  b  c  d
0  1  5  6  7
1  2  5  6  7
2  3  5  6  7
3  4  5  6  7
```

Here's a merge that uses the column `'a'`:

```
>>> pd.merge(pd.merge(t1, t2, on='a'), t3, on='a')
   a  b  c  d
0  1  5  6  7
1  2  5  6  7
2  3  5  6  7
3  4  5  6  7
```

If you need to merge an indeterminate number of dataframes, you can use the `reduce` function, found in the functools module, with `partial` to set the column to join on (as well as other parameters you desire):

```
>>> import functools
>>> functools.reduce(functools.partial(pd.merge, on='a'), [t1, t2, t3])
   a  b  c  d
0  1  5  6  7
1  2  5  6  7
2  3  5  6  7
3  4  5  6  7
```

If you're dealing with data that is so large that you're concerned about RAM, csv is the wrong way to go. csv is the wrong way to go in general. You should use sqlite instead, at a minimum. Keep it all in the same language and the same DB structure, and you reduce problems, improve testability and maintainability, and make your life easier in general.

Comment: Is there an explanation for why csv is the wrong way to go ?

Comment: @Jidder, I added more of a explanation.